# JQuery getting streamed content without freezing browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sorry if this question appears to be a duplicate, but in none of the others I could find an answer that actually explains the issue and solution properly.

I have a python application which is streaming some HTML data while it processes the request (and the stream works properly), on the client side I want to have a box to be updated while new data is being sent by the server so I came up with a JQuery `get` request which is fired by pressing a button.

The problem is that the box gets updated only when the jQ request completes, so the question:
Is it possible to update the HTML (DOM) while the request jQ request is being executed?

Below the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#rescanevts').on('click',
    function(e) {
      $('#output').show();


      $.get('/actions/rescan/events/switch/{{data.switch.id}}',function(data) {
    $('#output').append(data)
      });
    }
  );    
});
```

Comment: Yes. You'll need to use a setInterval that periodically grabs the contents of the xhr.responseText property.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new into this whole AJAX/JS stuff so could you please provide some good examples?

Answer (score 0):

I started to research on the googlenet and found some alternatives, but most of them were not documented (jQuery Stream aka Portal) and others we really obscure to a noob like me.

I discovered the `onreadystatechange` property of the `XMLHttpRequest` and used it to update the HTML in my message box. Below the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var outframe = $('#outcontent');

  // Function which will be called whenever the XML requester has a state
  // change (normally new data being received) and will update the full content
  // with new data (including what was already in the buffer)
  // This can be expensive in long streams
  function reqListener () {
    outframe.html(this.responseText);
  };

  $('#rescanevts').on('click',
    function(e) {
      $('#output').show();
      // The XMLHttpRequest 
      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.open("get", "/actions/rescan/events/switch/{{data.switch.id}}", true);
      oReq.onreadystatechange = reqListener;
      oReq.send();
    }
  );    
});
```